# Preventing Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) Attacks

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I've read the below link and fully understand except for one part. I asked a question in the comment on the link, but nobody responded.

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-(csrf)-attacks

Where do we call the "**ValidateRequestHeader**"?

Can someone please be able to answer this?

Answer (score 2):

Depends if you are using MVC or WebApi to validate the request.

For Web Api I would put it in a [Message Handler](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/http-message-handlers).

And for MVC I would put it in an [Action Filter](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs).

That way the request is validated before it reaches your controller's action method and since that is a cross cutting concern it can be easily applied to any controller or action just by decorating it with an attribute.

MVC already has a [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute built.  I think for webapi you need to handroll your own.

Comment: But the "ValidateRequestHeader" method has to be called from somewhere. Where is it called from?

Comment: you dont need that method.. All you need is to inspect the Request Header "RequestVerificationToken".  Then apply your check against that request header value.